# Debugging in a context manager in python

Tags: python, contextmanager

I have quite a complex context manager integrated into my software and I am making some changes to them. How can I get a full error log that occurs within the with the block. All I can do so far is:

```
print exc_type
print exc_val
print exc_tb
```

But this does not reveal the full traceback of the error. How can I get the classic error log à la `Traceback (most recent call last):`

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
import traceback
```

and then

```
traceback.print_exc()
```